# SQL Server 2008 - Keyboard Shortcut Key to do SQL Query Formatting

Tags: sql-server-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

Do you know the Keyboard shortcut key in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to do SQL Query Formatting?

Comment: It doesn't have any built in query formatting does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another great tool for this is [Red-Gate SQL Prompt Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) which allows you to define your own SQL coding style, and easily reformat any crappy SQL code that gets dumped on you :-)

It's not free - but easily worth every penny it costs!

Comment: yes I was looking for something like that and now using "SQL Assistant"

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

*I hope this will help future readers if OP is already found the solution.*

There is no built in formatting in SSMS but there are free SSMS Addins such as [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) you can use for this.

Apart from this you can also try SSMS tools pack but note that it’s not free for SQL 2012.

Answer (score 2):

there are no built in formatting functions like a Beautifier or Formatter program.

tab (including while a section of code is selected), space, backspace, delete, etc. and the expected ones.  I use alt+mouse click+drag to select "square" sections of code.

here are all of the [SQL Server Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

Are you looking for something like this: [Format SQL Beautifier
 software](http://format.software.informer.com/download-format-sql-beautifier/) ??

Comment: yes I was looking for something like that and now using "SQL Assistant"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Shift + Q will give you a Query Designer window from which you can copy formatted query.

Answer (score -1):

Their is no shortcut keys in sql server 2008,2010,2014,2015...

The simple way visit http://www.sql-format.com/ and format.